# What is the difference between to_json VS JSON.parse() in Ruby?

Tags: json, ruby

Can someone explain the difference between `to_json` and `JSON.parse()` in Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're opposite methods. `to_json` converts the given object to a JSON string, while `JSON.parse()` parses the given JSON string and converts it to an object:

```
json_string = {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}.to_json
# => "{\"first_name\":\"John\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\"}"

json_object = JSON.parse(json_string)
# => {"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe"}

json_object['first_name']
# => "John"
```